# PHP - Deny access to a page when entering not from a link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

Is there a way to deny access to a certain page but only when accessing it via url? I have a link which loads a page into `div` element but don't want anyone accessing that page via url (e.g. `<address>/pages/contact.php`). I want it to redirect back to `index.php`.

**jQuery load code:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.content').load('pages/home.php');

    var selector = '.side .nav li a';
    $(selector).click(function() {
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = 'pages/' + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0] + '.php';
        $('.content').load(target);
    }); 
});
```

**My `php` code that doesn't work (redirects `content` to `index.php` as well):**

```
<?php 
    header('Location: ../index.php');
?>
```

Comment: A very unreliable way would be to check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want a link system without page refreshing (link -> load to content `div`) and I don't want anyone just checking the page location in `.js` code and going there manually (it's only plain text w/ `php` code)